# How to implement a mediaquery inside styledcomponents?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a reactcomponent that should have a mediaquery:

```
const CalloutsContainer = styled.div`
@media (min-width: 900px) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
`;
```

The beginning of the component looks like this:

```
<CalloutsContainer>
        <Container>
          <CallOut>
            <h4>Feature 1</h4>
            <p>
            ...
```

Unfortunately I can't get it to work: the columns are displayed in rows instead of columns. How can I get the mediaquery working?  [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/my4qz613jx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either apply the style to the `Container` (not the `CalloutContainer`) or remove it. Note that `CalloutContainer` has a single child so your flex modifications will not make a difference.

Alternatively, you can further nest your rule:

```
@media (...) {
  > * {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```